# How to get the percentage of values depending on timestamp with mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I want to be show the percentage of the values : 0,1,2 in the *field_couleurs_badge_value* column depending on the timestamps in the *revision_timestamp* column everyday,everyweek and everymonth between 08:00 A.M and 19:00 and exclude the weekends.

An example of the result that i want is :

```
Yesterday value 0 has 50%
          value 1 has 30%
          value 2 has 20%

Last week value 0 has 40%
          value 1 has 40%
          value 2 has 20%

Last month value 0 has 30%
           value 1 has 30%
           value 2 has 40%
```

I have a mysql table with three rows (I put the dots for clarity):

```
revision_id, field_couleurs_badge_value, revision_timestamp
3724......., 0........................., 1491581853
4025......., 1........................., 1506418602
4026......., 2........................., 1506523134
4028......., 1........................., 1508232519
4029......., 2........................., 1508232886
```

Here is the code to create the table :

```
CREATE TABLE 'badge_stats' (
'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
'entity_id' VARCHAR(45) NULL,
'revision_id' VARCHAR(45) NULL,
'field_couleurs_badge_value' VARCHAR(45) NULL,
'revision_timestamp' VARCHAR(45) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ('id'));
INSERT INTO badge_stats VALUES('1', '3491', '3724', '1', '1491581853');
INSERT INTO badge_stats VALUES('2', '3491', '4026', '2', '1506523134');
INSERT INTO badge_stats VALUES('3', '3491', '4028', '1', '1508232519');
INSERT INTO badge_stats VALUES('4', '3491', '4029', '0', '1508232886');
```

What's the best way to do it ?

Here is my code to display the values with php :

```
$sql = "SELECT id, entity_id, revision_id, field_couleurs_badge_value, revision_timestamp FROM badge_stats";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


// Create table to display values
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>id</th><th>entity_id</th><th>revision_id</th><th>field_couleurs_badge_value</th><th>revision_timestamp</th>";
echo "</tr>";


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    //  output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $id = $row["id"];       
        $entity_id = $row["entity_id"];     
        $revision_id = $row["revision_id"];     
        $field_couleurs_badge_value = $row["field_couleurs_badge_value"];       
        $revision_timestamp = $row["revision_timestamp"];

        echo "<th>";        
        echo $id;       
        echo "</th>";               
        echo "<th>";        
        echo $entity_id;        
        echo "</th>";               
        echo "<th>";        
        echo $revision_id;
        echo "</th>";
        echo "<th>";    
        echo $field_couleurs_badge_value;   
        echo "</th>";   
        echo "<th>";    
        echo  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $revision_timestamp); 
        echo "</th>";
        echo "</tr>";


    }

}
else {

    echo "Error !";

}


echo "</table>";

$conn->close();
```

Comment: You want to show the percentage of `0,1,2` compared to what?

Comment: Compared to each other, i want to be able to tell how much time is the value 0 is displayed everyday,everyweek and everymonth between 08:00 A.M and 19:00 and exclude the weekends and the same with the 1 and 2.
Something like 50% for 0 and  30% for 1 and 20% to 2
I hope i was clear enough

Comment: All you've done is echo the values from the database. There are no calculations being performed. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @usethe23 Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes, i know it's because i don't know how to calculate the values with the timestamps. I'm not able to find a way to substract between the timestamps values and show them as percentages.

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Comment: @Strawberry Something like 50% for 0 and 30% for 1 and 20% to 2

Comment: Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: I've edited the question, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get percentage, we need to get some counts, and then we can calculate percentages. Seems like a query of this form would get us the result we are after:

```
  SELECT v.cnt_zero / v.cnt_all * 100.0    AS pct_zero
       , v.cnt_one  / v.cnt_all * 100.0    AS pct_one
       , v.cnt_two  / v.cnt_all * 100.0    AS pct_two
    FROM (
           ...
         ) v
```

To get the counts, that looks like a job for conditional aggregation.

We can use an expression to check a condition, and return a 1 or 0.

```
  SELECT IF( t.field_couleurs_badge_value = '0'            ,1,0)
       , IF( t.field_couleurs_badge_value = '1'            ,1,0)
       , IF( t.field_couleurs_badge_value = '2'            ,1,0)
       , IF( t.field_couleurs_badge_value IN ('0','1','2') ,1,0)
    FROM badge_stats t
   WHERE ...
```

And we can use `SUM` aggregate on those expressions to add up the 1s and 0s.

If we want to count rows with any value of in the `field_couleurs_badge_value` in "all" rows (including rows that don't have a '0','1' or '2' in that column), we could do that as well.

For the timestamp value, we can convert that into a MySQL TIMESTAMP or DATETIME datatype, and use the convenient builtin functions.

The `FROM_UNIXTIME` function will convert a unix-style timestamp value (32-bit integer seconds from beginning of era) into a DATETIME in the current MySQL session time zone (`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone'`)

```
  FROM_UNIXTIME( 1491581853 )
```

We can check if the time is "between 08:00 and 19:00".  We'll take this to mean that the check should be inclusive of '08:00:00.000' up thru and including '19:00:00.000'.

Normally when we work with time ranges, we avoid overlaps by doing checks **>=** start and **<** end,  so that we don't ever have a time on a boundary that gets included in two separate ranges. For example, does 19:00:00 belong in the range  8am-7pm or does it belong in the range 7pm-11pm.  (When we're counting rows in ranges, we typically don't want to count a row in two distinct ranges.)

We can use the `HOUR` function or `DATE_FORMAT` function to extract the hours, or the time. My preference would be to pull the whole time hh:mm:ss

```
  DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(1491581853), '%T')
```

And the string returned by that can compared to literals to see if the time falls into a time range:

```
     DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(1491581853), '%T') >= '08:00:00'
 AND DATE_FORMAT( FROM_UNIXTIME(1491581853), '%T') <= '19:00:00'
```

Similarly, to "exclude the weekends", we can use the `WEEKDAY` function or the `DATE_FORMAT` function to extract the day of the week

```
 AND WEEKDAY( FROM_UNIXTIME(1491581853), '%T') < 5
```

---

Putting all of that together, we get something like this:

```
  SELECT v.cnt_zero / v.cnt_012 * 100.0    AS pct_zero
       , v.cnt_one  / v.cnt_012 * 100.0    AS pct_one
       , v.cnt_two  / v.cnt_012 * 100.0    AS pct_two
       , v.cnt_012  / v.cnt_all * 100.0    AS pct_012
    FROM (
           SELECT SUM(IF( t.field_couleurs_badge_value = '0'            ,1,0)) AS cnt_zero
                , SUM(IF( t.field_couleurs_badge_value = '1'            ,1,0)) AS cnt_one
                , SUM(IF( t.field_couleurs_badge_value = '2'            ,1,0)) AS cnt_two
                , SUM(IF( t.field_couleurs_badge_value IN ('0','1','2') ,1,0)) AS cnt_012
                , SUM(1)                                                       AS cnt_all
             FROM badge_stats t
            WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME( t.revision_timestamp +0),'%T') >= '08:00:00'
              AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME( t.revision_timestamp +0),'%T') <= '19:00:00'
              AND WEEKDAY(    FROM_UNIXTIME( t.revision_timestamp +0)     ) < 5
         ) v
```

The specification is a little unclear what we are supposed to do with rows with values other than '0','1' and '2'... whether those are supposed to be included in the count of "all". As the specification is refined, we can tweak the query.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday

---

To get the percentages for various date ranges, those conditions can be included in the conditionals in the aggregate expressions.

First we need to have expressions that return us the begin and end of the datetime ranges we want to check. These definitions may not suit your use case, but as an example...

```
 SELECT DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(DATE(NOW()))+8 DAY AS blw  -- begin last week
      , DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(DATE(NOW()))+1 DAY AS elw  -- end last week (same as begin this week)
      , DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH  AS blm  -- begin last month
      , DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 0 MONTH  AS elm  -- end last month (same as begin this month)
```

We can test those expressions (use a user-defined variable in place of `NOW()` so we test behavior with various datetimes, e.g. a sunday, on the first of the month, etc.) and tweak the expressions until we get the behavior we want.

```
  blw         elw         blm         elm
  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
  2017-10-15  2017-10-22  2017-09-01  2017-10-01
```

We can use a query like that as an inline view, so we can reference the values by the assigned alias.  Given that the datetimes in the table are unix-style timestamps (why are these stored as character, and not int?), we can convert MySQL DATETIME/TIMESTAMP into unix-style timestamp integers with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function.

Shortening the column names for the purposes of this demonstration,  `revision_timestamp` to `ts`, and `field_couleurs_badge_value` to `fcbv`, something like this:

```
SELECT v.lw_cnt_zero / v.lw_cnt_012 * 100.0    AS lw_pct_zero
     , v.lw_cnt_one  / v.lw_cnt_012 * 100.0    AS lw_pct_one
     , v.lw_cnt_two  / v.lw_cnt_012 * 100.0    AS lw_pct_two

     , v.lm_cnt_zero / v.lm_cnt_012 * 100.0    AS lm_pct_zero
     , v.lm_cnt_one  / v.lm_cnt_012 * 100.0    AS lm_pct_one
     , v.lm_cnt_two  / v.lm_cnt_012 * 100.0    AS lm_pct_two

  FROM (               -- last week  
        SELECT SUM(IF( t.ts+0 >= d.blw AND t.ts+0 < d.elw AND t.fcbv = '0'           ,1,0)) AS lw_cnt_zero
             , SUM(IF( t.ts+0 >= d.blw AND t.ts+0 < d.elw AND t.fcbv = '1'           ,1,0)) AS lw_cnt_one
             , SUM(IF( t.ts+0 >= d.blw AND t.ts+0 < d.elw AND t.fcbv = '2'           ,1,0)) AS lw_cnt_two
             , SUM(IF( t.ts+0 >= d.blw AND t.ts+0 < d.elw AND t.fcbv IN ('0','1','2'),1,0)) AS lw_cnt_012
                       -- last month 
             , SUM(IF( t.ts+0 >= d.blm AND t.ts+0 < d.elm AND t.fcbv = '0'           ,1,0)) AS lm_cnt_zero
             , SUM(IF( t.ts+0 >= d.blm AND t.ts+0 < d.elm AND t.fcbv = '1'           ,1,0)) AS lm_cnt_one
             , SUM(IF( t.ts+0 >= d.blm AND t.ts+0 < d.elm AND t.fcbv = '2'           ,1,0)) AS lm_cnt_two
             , SUM(IF( t.ts+0 >= d.blm AND t.ts+0 < d.elm AND t.fcbv IN ('0','1','2'),1,0)) AS lm_cnt_012

          FROM ( SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(DATE(NOW()))+8 DAY) AS blw -- begin last week
                      , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(DATE(NOW()))+1 DAY) AS elw -- end last week
                      , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)  AS blm -- begin last month
                      , UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-01') - INTERVAL 0 MONTH)  AS elm -- end last month
               ) d
          JOIN badge_stats t
            ON t.ts+0 >= d.blm
         WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME( t.ts +0),'%T') >= '08:00:00'
           AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME( t.ts +0),'%T') <= '19:00:00'
           AND WEEKDAY(    FROM_UNIXTIME( t.ts +0)     ) < 5
       ) v
```

Note that the comparisons to the "end" of the range is "less than". The value we're comparing to is actually the beginning datetime of the next range. We want values up to (but not including) the beginning of the next range.

Note that we included a predicate in the ON clause of the JOIN to exclude rows from `badge_stats` that are earlier than the earliest datetime we're interested in, in this case, the beginning of last month.

We are also adding a zero (+0) to the references to the varchar `regression_timestamp` column, to convert to numeric, so we can compare to numerics. (We don't want to do character comparisons on integer values.)

This can be extended to also generate percentages for "yesterday". Add expressions to the inline view `d` to return the beginning of yesterday and the start of today.

And repeat the same pattern we used for "last week" and "last month", with expressions referencing "beginning of yesterday" and "end of yesterday".

Comment: wow thank you very much ! i'll try this then come back to tell you if it works ! Many thanks !!

Comment: Thank you again for your answer ! You've based your answer on the count of how many times the number 0,1,2 are occuring, but i want to take in considration the timestamp, if the number 0 stays for a longer time the percentage should be higher, not based on the count but on the timestamp.

What i want to know is how much time in a day, week, month the values 0,1,2 are displayed based on the timestamp.

Thank you for your answer again, it will help me in getting closer to the way of doing it

Comment: Maybe it would be a good idea to create a table that counts the minuts of every timestamp then use your answer to display the percentages